# Sorted subcategory list with thumbnails

Tags: static-block, category-tree

I have the following block:

```
<div id="home-subcat-container">
<div class="wallcontainer">
<?php
    //gets all sub categories of parent category 'Brands'
    $cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3)->getChildren();
    $catIds = explode(',',$cats);

    $categories = array();
    foreach($catIds as $catId) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId); 
        $categories[$category->getName()] = array(
            'url' => $category->getUrl(),
            'img' => $category->getImageUrl()
        );
    }
?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($categories as $name => $data): ?>
            <li>
                <p><a href="<?php echo $data['url']; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a></p>
                 <a href="<?php echo $data['url']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $data['img']; ?>" /></a>
            </li>   
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

This produces a list of children categories for the given category but it is not sorted.

I have also tried the following code:

```
<?php
$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3)->getChildrenCategories();
?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($cats as $category): ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

This gets me a sorted list but without the possibility of thumbnails.

Any way to combine both solutions?
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I had to get the category ID as well:

```
<?php
$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3)->getChildrenCategories();

?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($cats as $category): ?>
<?php $catId = $category->getId(); ?>
    <li>
        <p><a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a></p>
         <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId)->getImageUrl(); ?>" /></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```